# What is a Module in context of an Android JNI App?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI, C++ and make files. In the `Application.mk` of my sample Android-JNI-C++ project their is a `APP_MODULES` property.

The [Android NDK documentation](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/APPLICATION-MK.html) just says

> APP_MODULES
>
> This variable is optional. If not defined, the NDK will
>   build by default *all* the modules declared by your Android.mk, and
>   any sub-makefile it may include.
>
> If APP_MODULES is defined, it must be a space-separated list of module
>   names as they appear in the LOCAL_MODULE definitions of Android.mk
>   files. Note that the NDK will compute module dependencies
>   automatically.

And I know from [other questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5835926/199048), that each module needs it's own `Android.mk`.

But what is a module in this context? What is the advantage of having several modules instead of having only one?

Comment: It is same as having different building blocks. You can have conditional compilation of modules as well as conditional compilation within the modules, improve compilation times when you make a small change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many modules defined in a single Android.mk. Each library - static or shared - you build or copy (that's called prebuilt lib) is a separate module.

The main reason to split the code in separate libraries on Android is the same as on all other platforms: *divide et impera*. In the NDK build scheme, there is one more case: it's much easier to specify compilation parameters per module, so if you need to [mix -std=c99 and -std=c++0x](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/eUW7X_rKZPs/discussion), the simple workaround is to use two static libraries.